# Find data node js using knex

Tags: node.js, passport.js, knex.js

i just created a function to enter using google oauth. If the data has the same google user id, the data should not add with the same google user id, but what I created can't compare the same data.

Here's my function:

```
// Check user
    const existingUser = new User(database)
    await existingUser.getUserGoogleId({ google_user_id: profile.id })
    if (existingUser) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('User already exists in our DB')
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log(existingUser)
        return done(null, existingUser)
    }
```

And here's my repository:

```
async getUserGoogleId(google_user_id) {
    const query = this.db
        .select(
            'id',
            'google_user_id',
            'username',
        )
        .from(TABLE_NAME)
        .where({
            google_user_id,
        })

    return query.first()
}
```

Can you guys tell me and maybe give some improvement from it? Thank's. sorry if I have a bad explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an object to your `getUserGoogleId`, then in the where clause you are creating a nested object.

The object that you pass to the `where` clause looks like:

```js
{
  google_user_id: {
    google_user_id: 'some-id';
  }
}
```

All you need to fix this is pass the object it self:

```js
async getUserGoogleId(google_user_id) {
  return this.db
    .select('id', 'google_user_id', 'username')
    .from(TABLE_NAME)
    .where(google_user_id)
    // --------^
    .first();
}
```

Tip: enable `.debug()` at the end of the query to check what query & params are passed to the DB.